# Loading input as a string with Langchain

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, gpt-3, chromadb

I've been trying to load the dynamic user queries and the answers that I receive for it into Chroma DB in langachain. I have only options to load input as documents in langchain. Is there a possibility to load input strings in langchain ?

I have attached the function in which I'm trying to pass the query and answer as parameters receieved from earlier functions.

```
    def store_query_and_answer(query, answer):
      embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
      Chroma.from_documents(documents=query, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory="./")
      Chroma.from_documents(documents=answer, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory="./")
```

Instead of loading this as a document, I want to load the queries as a line of strings. For example if I asked a query and got an answer like below from another function,

query : What is your name ?

answer : My name is XYZ.

Please post your suggestions on this, I truly appreciate your time and efforts ❤

Comment: Please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your function as below, [query] and [answer] both are list of string, you can pass single list entry in query and answer respectively

```
         def store_query_and_answer(query, answer):
              embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
              Chroma.from_documents(documents=[query], embedding=embeddings, persist_directory="./")
              Chroma.from_documents(documents=[answer], embedding=embeddings, persist_directory="./")
```